# Starting preload

Tags: preload

I just installed `preload`. I found, that `sudo /etc/init.d/preload start` command is starting it - I need to do it after every boot up? Maybe it's starting automatically? If not - how can I set it to do it?

Comment: it will start on every boot ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preload starts up automatically when you turn on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to install preload:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install preload
```

Yup, preload will start by itself when you boot your ubuntu system. You can use top command to check if it's running

```
top
```

You should see preload running.